# maximo anywhere login issues in ipad device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, maximo-anywhere

Maximo Anywhere working fine in simulator, not able to login from iPad device (any device).

Response is NULL from adapter - Login call with an error (Security Realm). Attached the logs for the same. Kindly help. I checked wlclient.properties also but i not able to login. at same time i can able to login worklight simulator.

Thanks advance

Comment: You did not attach any logs.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i fix that issues and one more help i want . i try to install apps for my ipad device they anywhere given barcode scanner and map plugin is not working and i search for project there does not available for native plugin classes.. any idea please let me know.

Comment: Please write the answer for the question. Do not keep questions unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

above that issues i resolved. Below that property resolved my issues,

> NSAppTransportSecurity 
>   NSAllowsArbitraryLoads

And i following this links are very helpful us.

1. https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/09/ats-and-bitcode-in-ios9/
2. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html